To destroy the IP address from Azure
I want to destroy the IP using Terraform, and for that, I have provided two resources (that have to be destroyed). Since it is an existing resource, I have an import block (Azure resource). I want to delete two different IPs under the same subscriptions, did I want to add the import block for all the resources (here I have two)? If there are any other methods to destroy multiple IP resources kindly let me know.
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>4.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
    subscription_id = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

import {
  id = provider::azurerm::normalise_resource_id("/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/aaaaaa/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/TestVm-ip")
  to = azurerm_public_ip.TestVm
}
# import {
#   id = provider::azurerm::normalise_resource_id("/subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/websitei-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/UBUNTU22-IP")
#   to = azurerm_public_ip.example
# }


resource "azurerm_public_ip" "TestVm" {
  name                = "TestVm-ip"
  resource_group_name = "aaaaaa"
  location            = "eastus"
  allocation_method   = "Static" 
  sku                 = "Standard"  
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                = "UBUNTU22-IP"
  resource_group_name = "websitei-rg"
  location            = "eastus"
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  #sku                 = "Basic"
}



Destroying public IP using terraform

To import the multiple resources without mentioning all the terraform configuration of same type you can use for_each
block under import section, for more details follow the stack link answered by markoE
Alternatively, You don’t need to import existing resource to into state, you can run PowerShell commands by using null resource in terraform which directly delete the existing IPs under the subscription without importing.
Delpublicip.ps1
$rgName = "azuretest"

$publicIpNames = @("VenkatIP", "VenkatIP1", "VenkatIP3")

foreach ($publicIpName in $publicIpNames) {
    Remove-AzPublicIpAddress -Name $publicIpName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Force
}


IP.tf
    resource "null_resource" "Powershell_script" {
      provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = <<-EOT
          ${path.module}/Delpublicip.ps1
        EOT
        interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
      }
    }



Note: Make sure to save both files in same directory

Terraform apply
After executing the code, the public IPs has been deleted from portal.

